# How to show progress bar on button click until ads is loaded, After ads is loaded hide progress bar and show ads without button click button again

Tags: android, android-progressbar, rewardedvideoad

When I click button progress bar showing up but not showing ads even it is loaded. only show toast OnRewardedVideoAdsLoaded. I have to click again to show ads..

after ad is loaded, progress bar is stop but not showing ads. its only toast.
when i click button again then ads is showing..

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
private int coin;
private TextView bp;
private Button btn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    loadRewardedVideoAd();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            showRewardedVideo();
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {

                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
            }

        }
    });


    bp = findViewById(R.id.bp);
    coin = 0;
    bp.setText(coin + "  BP");
}



private void showRewardedVideo() {

    if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }
}




@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    savedInstanceState.putInt("coin", 0);

}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    int coin = savedInstanceState.getInt("coin");
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.resume(this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.pause(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.destroy(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }
}



// "ca-app-pub-5399035702215687/5287697226"


private void addCoins(int coins) {
    coin += coins;
    bp.setText(coin + "  BP");
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {



    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOPENED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this,
            String.format(" onRewarded! currency: %s amount: %d", reward.getType(),
                    reward.getAmount()),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    addCoins(reward.getAmount());
}



@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication()
{     btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}


@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your question well now and I get what the problem is. You are not showing the Ad once it's ready, you are checking its readiness only when you click the button.

The best approach is the following:

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

              if(!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()){
                  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Ad is not loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
              }

        }
    });

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: thanks for reply...      I have tried this code.. Its automatically show ads. when ads is loaded... without button clicked...

Comment: then remove the `loadRewardedVideoAd()` from `onCreate()`

Comment: I want, when I clicked Button, If ads is not loaded then show toast 'ads is not loaded'  when ads is loaded then show ads without button press **again**

Comment: check the edit and remove the loadRewardedVideoAd() from onCreate() as I told you.

Comment: okay.. I have removed loadRewardedVideoAd()  from onCreate() but its not working even button is clicked

Comment: when i put loadRewardedVideoAd() in onClick()  again same problem repeating. I have press button again to show ads..

Comment: I told you don't put it in onClick. Just remove it from onCreate(). You don't want to show any ad when you click the button, you only want to load if it's not loaded (by showing the ProgressBar of course).